# Has someone been removing [sap]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I was going to add [sap](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sap) to the 160 year old log question. But... I saw it was only tagged on one other question. There are several questions here that talk about sap.

Does the community feel that the tag should not exist? I could have sworn it was on some of my questions as well.

Comment: I don't know why someone would be removing it.  I'm pro sap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sap seems to be a perfectly fine tag for this site.  It happens to be a common problem for people to deal with.

Comment: I added sap to what I thought were appropriate questions.